# What is the difference between monoclonal and polyclonal antibodies?

Tags: antibody

I'm having trouble to see a difference between monoclonal and polyclonal antibodies. The way I understand it:

- Monoclonal antibodies are produced by the same "clone" or "line" of B-cells and, thus, can bind to a single epitope for some antigen.
- Polyclonal antibodies are produced by multiple "clones" or "lines" of B-cells and, thus, can bind to different epitopes for the same antigen.

However, it is also my understanding that:

- Every B-cell can produce only one kind of antibodies; i.e., the antibody molecules produced by an individual B-cell can all bind to only one epitope.

And so, when combining all these concepts, I can't really find any fundamental difference between monoclonal and polyclonal antibodies. To me, the distinction is only applicable when one is discribing the composition of a given substance (i.e. if such a substance contains Abs produced by a single line of B-cells or by multiple lines), but otherwise there's no difference between an individual "monoclonal" Ab molecule and an individual "polyclonal" Ab molecule; i.e., they'd both have the same general properties and functions.

I'd like to know if there is something I'm misunderstanding or if there's some information I'm missing.

Comment: I'd recommend looking into [VDJ recombination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V(D)J_recombination) to learn more about the underlying means by which antibody specificity / identity is defined. A clone of mature B cells derives from a single recombination event.

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please do us the courtesy of finishing the [Tour] and then read the Help on asking questions, from which you will see that we require you to show the research you have done before posting. Wikipedia and a hundred other sites on the web explain the difference between monoclonal and polyclonal antibodies.  Read them carefully.

Comment: @David I'm aware that there are many sites on the Internet that explain the differences between these concepts, but I just like posting questions publicly so that fellow humans can condenscendingly and unhelpfuly answer to them. I also believe that I've clearly summerized in my question all the relevant information I've gathered so far from what I've read; please do me the courtesy of reading my question carefully. Thank you.

Comment: On reflection, I think that a lot of this question comes down to the meaning of the word "clone". Re: David's note about triviality, it is only trivial if you have a very clear idea of what this word means, as the root of polyclonal (many clones) vs. monoclonal (one clone).

Comment: Let me start again. You write "I'd like to know if there is something I'm misunderstanding". The answer is yes. You are thinking that the term "monoclonal antibody" is a description of an individual protein molecule, and implies that that individual protein molecule is chemically or structurally different from an individual protein molecule designated "polyclonal antibody". Antibodies are important tools in biological research, and for which they are generated artificially. Polyclonal and monoclonal refers to the heterogeneity or otherwise of the generated **populations**…

Comment: (cont)…So, as many accounts make clear, the key thing about monoclonal antibodies is that they are preparations (mixtures) in which all antibodies are identical in amino acid sequence (and which can continue to be generated to sustain research). This homogeneity of monoclonal antibody preparations allows applications/uses that are not possible with polyclonal antibodies, in which the individual molecules, although binding to the same epitope, have different aa sequences (and affinities and specificities). The applications/uses of monoclonals are many, and are amply described in the literature.

Answer (score 1):

Monoclonal antibodies are like having a bag of tennis balls. They're all tennis balls.

Polyclonal antibodies are like having a bag of sports balls. If some of them are tennis balls, yes, they're the same as the monoclonal antibody tennis balls. But, the polyclonal antibody bag also contains baseballs and ping pong balls and basketballs. And there are far more possibly antibodies than there are sports balls, so it's most likely that your sports ball bag of antibodies doesn't have *any* tennis balls or any other specific ball you'd have thought of ahead of time, rather just a bunch of things that vaguely serve the purpose of being ball-like.

So yes, you're right, for an individual antibody, it's the same substance whether it's in a bag with only other identical antibodies or if it's in a bag with a bunch of other antibodies, but it still matters whether you have a bag of one antibody type versus a bag of lots of antibody types. The former is more standardized, you "get what you get" and it always will work the same; the latter is more diverse and binds multiple targets which in some sense makes it more robust (e.g., a small change in the target may prevent binding with one clone but not other clones).

Production is also different. Simplifying things a bit, for [monoclonal antibodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoclonal_antibody), you produce the antibodies by isolating an antibody-producing cell and making lots of copies of that cell to make lots of that same antibody. There can be some variation in production but generally they are thought of as "one antibody".

For [polyclonal antibodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyclonal_antibodies), you inject an animal with an antigen, and collect the antibodies that are produced. You expect to get different specific antibodies each time, the only thing standardized is the *antigen* presented. (you can also do this with cell culture like monoclonal antibodies, except using a culture derived from lots of different cells)

Comment: I'd add an important distinction is often that monoclonal Abs have often only been presented with a short fragments which is approximately the length of an epitope, whereas polyclonal have often been given larger fragments or even full-length proteins to target, resulting in a diversity of epitopes.

Comment: @Bryan Krause Thank you for your easily digestable explanation. I was wondering, if there was maybe genetic factors that would make monoclonal and polyclonal Ab molecules different in some small but important way (like differences in their binding sites or in their backbone structures).

Comment: @OldCrow No, it's all in the name: mono-clonal "one clone", poly-clonal "more than one clone", where "clone" means "line of antibody-producing cells".